# PHP mktime does not return big integer values on 64-bit system

Tags: php, 64-bit, strtotime, mktime, year2038

I have an issue with PHP function **mktime** when trying to get unix_timestamps bigger that for year 2038. I have 64-bit OS.

PHP version on server:
`php -v` gives
PHP 5.1.6 (cli) (built: Nov 29 2010 16:47:46)

`php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;'` gives
9223372036854775807

but

`php -r 'var_dump( mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 2099) );'` gives
bool(false)

On development server
`php -r 'var_dump( mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 2099) );'` gives
int(4078677600)

What may be the cause for this PHP function not to work properly on 64-bit system? Also **strtotime** does not work with dates where year is greater than 2038

Comment: Try to use `DateTime` class.

Comment: DateTime class is only available since (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0). As this point I have PHP 5.1.6 Upgrading is an option, but that's one of the last ones.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Who do you call? "Captain Hindsight!"

On a more serious note, for large date ranges I would use the traditional DB datetime storage method of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.  It is easily parsed and highly portable.

Using `DateTime` for runtime usage is most feasible, the latter string pattern for persistence.